# CSS Positioning for jquery player

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery player on my front page that seems centered and ok for me in Chrome and Safari.

But everyone else is seeing it on the left side of the screen for some reason.

I tried different variations of positions like absolute, relative and tried margins without positions..nothing seems to put it in place for all others.

the css for the div is:

```
#container {
width: 525px;
height: auto;
position: relative;
left: 373px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 10;
```

its on -

> www.tranceil.fm

Comment: I'll bet your using a 1280 x 1024 monitor, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the left property and adjust your margin to margin:0 auto;

```
#container {
width: 525px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: You can also remove `height: auto;` because `auto` is the default value when left undefined. Its a good practice to help keep CSS file-size down.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect. thanks soderslatt.
Chrome can help in many situations to test css while inspecting code online.
sometimes, useful testing on small or big screen, too.